# iText PdfAcroForm GetAcroForm not applicable for the types given

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I haven't been programming for a long time, and have never used the iText library before - I am sure that this will be a simple problem that I just do not understand correctly. I am trying to get the PdfAcroForm from a PdfDocument instance called 'pdf'. Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.*
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument
import com.itextpdf.forms.*
import com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfFormField
import com.itextpdf.forms.PdfAcroForm

//Initialize PDF document
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("C:/Users/Andy/Desktop/VA_Form.pdf"), new PdfWriter("C:/Users/Andy/Desktop/New_VA_Form.pdf"));

PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf,true);
//Map<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.GetFormFields();
```

This is returning the error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.itextpdf.forms.PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm() is applicable for argument types: (com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument, java.lang.Boolean) values: [com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument@101978d4, true]
Possible solutions: getAcroForm(com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument, boolean), getXfaForm()
```

I cannot determine whether I have not created a PdfDocument correctly, or whether I am just making a mistake with how to get the AcroForm from this PdfDocument? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first "possible solution" in the error message most likely is the solution, iText `PdfAcroForm` has a method:

```
getAcroForm(com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument, boolean)
```

but you used:

```
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf,true);
```

I.e. the initial 'g' in the method name has to be lowercase, not uppercase.

Comment: Thanks @mkl, I had tried that before but had discounted it due to getting a new error message `Script1.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument
 @ line 1, column 1.` which I was unsure of as well. Thank you for your help - do you know what the new error means?

Comment: Sorry ignore the last comment, I was having problems with the ScriptMaster for Filemaker file recognising new jar files that I added. Thanks again